# How to integrate JQGrid with Django/Python

Tags: jquery, python, django, jqgrid

Anybody out there who have tried to use [JQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) a Jquery plugin with django?

Please share your knowledge/code samples

Gath

Answer (score 3):

I've find a project that has already implemented integration
look at Google code http://code.google.com/p/django-jqgrid/

Comment: I'd also like to say that since getting on GitHub, django-jqgrid has been forked many times, and I actually use my own (pstch/django-jqgrid) fork in production environment. The author is also still active, accepting Pull Requests (the code was recently updated to fit Django 1.4), so if you feel things are outdated or not your way... update them or propose changes.

Comment: this repository use  django-simple-rest and not support for python3

Answer (score 1):

Is there any latest info on this? Looks like django-jqgrid not updated in a year

Comment: I think django-jqgrid is good enough to start: we've built our own classes to meet our specific needs

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [django-jquery-grid-admin](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-jquery-grid-admin/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

i implement jqgrid on django using JavaScript:

**1.-** Create a function in views.py for query(raw sql):

```
   def dictfetchall(cursor):
    # Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    desc = cursor.description
    return [
        dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]

    def ExampleGrid(request):
      cursor = connection.cursor()
      query = " SELECT name, email FROM personal_personal ";
      cursor.execute(query)
      result = dictfechtall(cursor)
    
      retur JsonResponse(result, safe=False)
```

**2.-** Create a url for Example function:

```
url(r'^grid_personal', ExampleGrid, name='grid_personal'),
```

**3.-** define the grid and pager on your template:

```
<table id="gridPersonal"></table>
<div id="pagerPersonal"></div>
```

Don't forget include in your template all **JS** and **CSS** required for **JQGRID**:

[Reference Jqgrid version JS](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/)

**4.-** Code Javascript i prefer use a external file js:

```
function getCookie(name) {
  
  var cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
      var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
          // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
          if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
          cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  //RETURN TOKEN
  return cookieValue;

}//end function getCookie


var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
$("#gridPersonal").jqGrid({
    url:'grid_personal',
    postData: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrftoken,
    },
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['Name', 'Email'],
    colModel: [
        {name: 'name', width: 40, sorttype:"string", align:'center'}},
        {name: 'email', width: 40, sorttype:"string", align:'center'}},
    ],
    loadonce: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    width: 900,
    height: 400,
    rowNum:100,
    pager: '#pagerPersonal',
    rownumbers: true,
    caption: "PERSONAL",
    shrinkToFit: true,
});
```

that is all, for this case i use the JqGrid version JavaScript.

Good Luck..!!

Answer (score -2):

I'm trying to use it for the first day today.  Right now I have imported an existing jquery app into a django project/app and now trying to get jqgrid to work with it.  The thing I'm running into is having the javascript file actually call the python script for the json call for jgrid.

I have no idea if this is working or not...I watch the apache logs and I don't see the file being served.  I can reach the python script fine in the browser directly.

Right now I'm just trying to go around django and get it to work with straight html/python/javascript.  In the example they just have the javascript file call a php file like this.

url:'server.php?q=1',

well mine is located at like http://localhost/pythonScripts/server.py with mod_python running.  I would love to get this working, but it is going to take alot of trial and error.  Hopefully I can eventually get it all the way to django.